# Passing values to module instance port through loops inside always block in verilog

Tags: instance, verilog

I need to access ports of module instance through for loop using verilg code, i'm trying to send inputs to a module instance repeatedly hoping every time the output for corresponding input get updated, unfortunately it is not happening because the inputs get passed only after execution exit the procedural block, please find the below code and let me know the possibilities, thanks in advance.

```
integer i,j;
always@(g_mtx,gi_mtx)
begin
for (i=1;i<3;i=i+1) 
for (j=1;j<3;i=j+1) 
   if(i!=j)
        begin
        L_in1=g_mtx[j][j];
        L_in2=gi_mtx[i][i];
        L_in3=gi_mtx[j][i];
        L_in4=g_mtx[j][i]; 
        Lmd[i][j]= L_out ;
        end
end
Lamda_top lmd (L_out,L_in1,L_in2,L_in3,L_in4,clk);//instance 

//here g_mtx,gi_mtx,Lmd are memories.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions differ depending on the context.

If this is for a testbench, all you need do is add some form of delay after simulating the inputs. Seeing as you are using a clock for the `Lamda_top` module, you can use the same clock as the delay source to ensure enough time has passed:

```
always @(g_mtx,gi_mtx) begin
  for (i=1; i<3; i=i+1) begin
    for (j=1; j<3; j=j+1) begin
      if(i!=j) begin
        L_in1=g_mtx[j][j];
        L_in2=gi_mtx[i][i];
        L_in3=gi_mtx[j][i];
        L_in4=g_mtx[j][i];

        repeat ([number of cycles it takes for Lamda_top to finish]) begin
          @(posedge clk);
        end
        @(negedge clk); // Ensure L_out has gotten the value from the function
        Lmd[i][j] = L_out;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, if this is instead for actual, synthesizable code, you will need to implement some sort of FSM to serialize the for-loops to only input one set of `L_inX` variables at a time.

Ultimately, both solutions involve ensuring that only one set of `L_inX` is passed through for each clock. Without knowing more context, its hard to say how best to handle this (should probably be some sort of pipeline, but thats alot more work to patch the provided code to implement)

Comment: Actually it is part of design code(MIMO Channel Equilizer) not a test bench, even though I put wait cycles the values passes to Lamda_top only after execution exit for loop, so only the final inputs are passed, I will try using FSM and let u know the status, thank you for your response.